# Package Repository for ARM32

Tags: repository, deb, arm, binary, embedded-system

Is there a repository of .deb packages for 32-bit ARM architecture. I'm having issues compiling several gnome packages and I'd rather acquire the binaries directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Debian and Arch repositories, but not Ubuntu.

https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs